# Compose email in Gmail and edit HTML: is there a browser addon for this?

Tags: web-browser, html-editor, gmail

Many WYSIWYG editors allow two modes:

- easy mode (with icons for bold, italic, etc.),
- but also a mode in which you can edit directly the HTML code.

**Is there a way to enable this in Gmail too, with a browser extension for Chrome or Firefox that would add such a "HTML edit" panel?** i.e. let the user modify the HTML codes for email.

Example of such HTML editor (WordPress):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now use the [Markdown here](https://markdown-here.com/) browser extension for this.

[image: screenshot of Markdown browser extension]

Of course this is not HTML, as mentioned in my question, but it allows the emails to be edited "with code" (Markdown) and do <kbd>CTRL+ALT+M</kbd> to have the rendered output.

That's the closest solution I found to what I was looking for. Finally Markdown is even better than editing HTML directly (If you are active on StackExchange, you're probably already convinced by this ;)).